# How to cite a play with no line numbers?

Tags: quotations, citation, mla

First off, this may not be an appropriate question for this site. I'm not sure. But I'm kind of in a hole and I'd really appreciate some help with this.

I need to integrate a quotation from *A Raisin in the Sun*. But, it doesn't have line numbers.

The manual I use (Diana Hacker's A Pocket Style Manual, 6th Edition) says it should be something like this:

blah blah happens when he/she says "blah blahdee blahdee blah"(1.2.48-49)

With the parantheses being (act.scene.line-numbers).

It also gives an example for if there are no parts or line numbers; it says to cite the page.

But, this has parts, but not line numbers.

What do I do since there are no line numbers?

Comment: What is wrong with act, scene and page number(s)? Include the edition you used in your bibliography (also when you use line numbers, the edition is still relevant!). Someone who wants to look up the quote in context will be fine ending up on the right page, even if the exact line is not given.

Comment: What oerkelens said. Also, live numbers don't really make sense with modern plays that aren't written in at least blank verse, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response; you're probably right. I was just freaking out a little last night because my my teacher grades formatting stuff like this hard.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about citation style, which belongs on writers.se

Answer (score 1):

As the comments note, you should include all the information you can but if there are no line numbers then you probably don't need to include them.

You mention your teacher grading things like this harshly but it is their job to teach you how to do this. I would stop by during office hours with the question or send an email.

Comment: "All the information you can" includes the page number and the edition. I'm sure this is a duplicate question: I've seen an answer which incorporates "page number and edition".